# Solution of a difference equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I want to solve the following difference equation for all $0<h<1$ and $c>0$:
$$\frac{a_{k+1}-a_k}{h}=-a_k $$
with the condition $a_0=c$.
Can someone explain how to solve equations of this kind?

Comment: I suggest you solve for $a_{k+1}$, do a few iterations, and see if you can't find a pattern. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Rewrite it as $a_{k+1} = (1-h)a_k = (1-h)^2a_{k-1}=...$. Can you take it from here?